# How can I resolve single quote problem while I insert?

Tags: php

What is the best way to avoid `\'` while we get the values from PHP post method and want to store in the database.  I have used simply , `echo $_POST['txtname'];`

it produces the output `Uncl\'es Jules`,  if enter name as `Uncl'es Jules`

Can any one suggest the better way?

Comment: if you have `magic_quotes` enabled, disable them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you have [**magic_quotes**](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled that's why it is escaping data automagically.

1. You should disable `magic_quotes`. [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) is how you can
2. Escape data with [**mysql_real_escape_string()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) while inserting them

If magic_quotes is not disabled with any reason you can use [**stripslashes**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) do remove those extra `\`.

```
echo stripslashes($data);
```

Comment: When retrieving values that have been escaped using mysql_real_escape_string() it should not be necessary to strip slashes they should be returned un-escaped. Just need to remember to pass again thru mysql_real_escape_string() if updating the value.

Answer (score 0):

It is escaping unsafe characters to store in the database. You actually want your SQL library to do this. If you do not do this, you are open to SQL Injection, and that's bad. :)

But it seems like you have magic quotes enabled. Do not use that and use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape your data before it is inserted into the database.

What you need to do is [revert all escaped characters back](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) when you display your data.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

use mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0):

Try using mysql_real_escape_string().

```
insert into tblTable1 set field1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtname']);
```

Or mysqli_real_escape_string(), also PDO has matching functions too.

Comment: On a side-note, mysql_real_escape_string() and it's variants should ALWAYS be used anyway. It will help minimise malicious SQL injection attempts.